# How to turn off segments on edge 510

Tags: garmin

Recently I've been getting notifications on my edge 510 of an upcoming segment (& and display when riding through it) - I can turn this off by hitting the red cross on screen when it comes up, but I'd like to completely disable this function and can't work our how. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have a Garmin, but it sounds like you're following a course, or doing a workout. See the [manual](http://static.garmincdn.com/pumac/Edge_510_OM_EN.pdf).

Comment: I think you'd have better luck with Garmin's support forums. https://forums.garmin.com/forumdisplay.php?363-Edge-510

Comment: @andy256 it's affecting any ride (I rarely preloaded routes)

Comment: @andy256: No, there's no need to follow a course or do a workout. If you have a *segment* uploaded to the device, the segment will trigger this "segment mode" display every time you ride through it. Another annoying issue with this functionality is that the "segment mode" screen will also pop up when you ride through that segment in reverse direction.

Comment: @AnT Sounds frustrating! I think I'm happy I don't have one :-)

Answer (score 5):

This works with firmware 5.0.

From the start screen, click the "folder" icon on the bottom left

Click "Strava Live Segments"

Click the Menu button on the bottom right (the three rows)

Click "Disable all"

Answer (score 2):

In Garmin connect, you can disable segments and then synch the 510.

Have you created your own segments? On the 510, you can go to segments under the folder menu, go to the very bottom option and choose delete all segments.