# How to turn off Live Segments on Garmin Edge 520 for good

Tags: garmin, strava

How do you completely disable Strava Live Segments on the Garmin Edge 520? I know how to disable segments on my device, and I know how to delete them, but after doing either of those, they ultimately appear back on my device after riding on new segments or the same ones.

I personally dislike the live segments, because most of the time I would just like to stay focused on the ride at hand and worry about if I PR'd after I'm done riding. As someone that leaves the sound on so I'm alerted every five miles, the sounds the Live segments make are very irritating. I know I can just hit up/down a couple times, but this gets really annoying, especially when I have gloves on (winter and all).

Please help, or at least confirm this isn't possible so I can start bugging Garmin to fix this in an update. I love everything about the 520 except this one "feature".

Comment: Here's [a question/answer](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/31242/how-to-turn-off-segments-on-edge-510) for the 510. Can you do something similar on your 520 to disable live segments?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's what I have done (deleted/disabled all segments) but new segments keep being put on the device. I'm hoping there's a solution to disable Live segments now and forever.

Comment: I have a 520 and have my Strava and Garmin connect synced but have never had live segments show up on my device.. perhaps because I don't have any starred segments/goals?

Comment: I think you may be on to something. The segments I keep seeing are likely starred. I go though routes quite regularly and star my favorite parts of the ride. So I guess my question now becomes: how do I remove Strava segments from automatically getting on my 520 without completely unlinking Strava?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable popular segments in Strava under Dashboard -> My Segments:

[image]

Then as long as you don't star any segments none will be synced to your device.

Comment: Ah, didn't realize that it was a setting in Strava. Now that I've turned this off, shouldn't I be able to star whatever segments I want and not have to worry about them appearing on the 520? I like starring segments so I hope that's not the case.

Comment: Yeah unfortunately if you star then they will sync to all connected devices.  But at least this way you will only see "your" starred segments and not all the other popular ones.

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer. The language on that button in Strava says "starred segments, goal segments and a selection of popular segments", so I'm curious if that means they'll be off for good now. I may reach out to Strava and see if they know how to turn them off permanently, their customer service is way more responsive than Garmin.

Answer (score 3):

On your 520 device, enter MENU, then TRAINING, then STRAVA LIVE SEGMENTS. Open SEGMENT OPTIONS, click on Enable/Disable, then select Disable All.